# Making Ajax call when using a "select-all" for checkboxes

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm struggling to figure out the best way to implement making an AJAX call for every checkbox that is selected when using a "select-all".

I've cobbled together making an AJAX call when checking individual checkboxes with the following code. This approach is probably cumbersome, but it is working well:

```
checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        var checkbox = checkboxes[i];
        checkbox.onclick = function () {
            var currentRow = this.parentNode.parentNode;
            var selectedVin = currentRow.getElementsByTagName("td")[1];

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/Search?handler=ExportList&vin=' + selectedVin.textContent.trim(),
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                        $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                },
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {

                    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

                },
                error: function (ex) {
                    console.log('Error occurred during processing.' + ex);
                }
            });
        };
    };
```

The block of code above is calling a RazorPage handler to store some data in session.

I'm also using this to do my select-all

```
 $('#select-all').click(function(event) {
        if (this.checked) {
            // Iterate each checkbox
            $(':checkbox').each(function() {
                this.checked = true;
            });
        }
        else {
            $(':checkbox').each(function () {
                this.checked = false;
            });
        }
    });
```

Looking for some guidance to make that same AJAX call for all of the checkboxes on the page once the "select-all" is checked. I've made a few attempts to integrate these 2 approaches together and nothing has been close yet.

Comment: I would have a separate JS function to handle the `select-all` check/uncheck. This will stop the page sending off N ajax requests to your back end. In addition, have a separate controller/method on the back end to handle the `select-all` that maybe accepts a `List<>` of your checkbox values. That way `select-all` is **one** request to the back end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Design**

One approach is to manually trigger the click event via [`element.click()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click).  But since we need choose between `checked` and `unchecked`, it's better to bind a `onchange` event as below :

```
someCheckbox.onchange=function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(this.checked){
        onSelected(this);    //trigger event to handle `check` 
    }else{
        OnUnselected(this);  //trigger event to handling `uncheck` 
    }
}
```

Now we're able to check some box in the following way:

```
//  var checkbox is a `Element`
if(checkbox.checked){} // do nothing if already checked
checkbox.checked = true;
onSelected(checkbox);
```

We could also uncheck it in a similar way.

**Implementation**

Firstly, create functions to handle the `check`/`uncheck` event

```
function onSelected(selectedElement){
    var currentRow = selectedElement.parentNode.parentNode;
    var selectedVin = currentRow.getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    console.log("seleced:",currentRow,selectedElement.name,selectedVin);
    // ... ajax call 
}

function onUnselected(unselectedElement){
    // ...
}

function onchange(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(this.checked) { onSelected(this); }
    else { onUnselected(this); }
}
```

And then register the `onchange` handler for every `checkbox` element:

```
for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    var checkbox = checkboxes[i];
    checkbox.onchange= onchange;
};
```

Lastly, register the `#select-all.onchange` event handler as below :

```
document.getElementById('select-all').onchange=function(event) {
    if (this.checked) {
        $(':checkbox').each(function () {
            if(this.checked){ return; } // do nothing if already checked
            this.checked = true;
            onSelected(this);
        });
    }
    else {
        $(':checkbox').each(function() {
            if(!this.checked) { return; } // do nothing if already unchecked
            this.checked = false;
            onSelected(this);
        });
    }
};
```

---

As a side note, I don't think it's a good idea to send so much ajax requests. It's better to refactor your server side code to receive a checked string list like `{s1:"checked",s2:"unchecked",s3:"checked","s4":"checked"}`. In this way, the browser will only send single one request. Obviously, it will be much more efficient.

Comment: This approach did work, certainly appreciate the help.I like the idea of the checked list for sure, I'll refactor it for that.